# Not able to install drivers for sql server on CENTOS

Tags: centos, php, sql-server

I am new at Linux OS but successfully installed apache, PHPMyAdmin, and MariaDB.

All works fine, but I have an issue and am not able to resolve it. My issue is establishing a connection to the SQL Express server which runs on WIndows machine on the same network. My script to sql ex

I was working with Windows environment with XAMPP installed I had no issues drivers for SQL express server were working.

When I do php -v in Centos, I get **PHP 7.4.21 (cli) version installed**. I was trying to install sqlsrv pdo drivers but have no luck. It tells me it is installed but i get issue when trying to establish a connection

Not sure how I can solve the issue. Attaching issue img [error in establishing connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u34i6.jpg)

Connection string I use

```
$serverName = "Machine\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TestDB", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"password" , "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $con ) {
  echo "It works";
}else{
  echo "Connection could not be established.";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: This is not a driver issue. It is most likely a wrong connection information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I am using the same connection as I used on xampp environment to connect to Windows Server Machine with SQL. Updated answer with the connection string. Is there anything you suggest I can do

Comment: Is the machine actually up and running?

Comment: Yes it is always up and running

Comment: OK, then go and do what the error message said to do.

Comment: Is there anyhting on Linux side that has to be done?  This sever was working when I had xampp on win 10. This connection to sql server worked. Now, after I moved to Centos it doesnt work :(

Comment: Have you read the error message and done what it suggests?

Comment: Yes I did, server allows remote connection.

Comment: Have you checked if the ports are open on the windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

sqlsrv pdo isn't for MariaDB.
for MariaDB you need to install php-mysql package. in Debian it's may be called php-mysql, or php7.4-mysql. in Centos it should be something like that also.
try to find it by

```
yum list php*mysql*
```

command.
if you would get success with that - try to install it with

```
yum install <packagename>
```

command, where  is name of package you have found.
P. S.: if you have some kind of error messages, you should post it by text, not by image like you did.